# Unsupervised clustering with Pearson correlation as measure of similarity

Tags: clustering

I have data from the cell lineage as samples:

```
Cell1 -> Cell2 -> Cell3
```

Then for each of the above samples I obtained the expression for 'coding' and 'non-coding' genes.
What I want to do is to identify cluster of genes for each cell lineage above, where the cluster should satisfy 
the following category:

```
Cluster Type 1:
non-coding UP (e.g. codingA: 1.00, 7.34, 50.10)
coding UP     (e.g. codingB: 10.00, 13.5, 40.10)
pearson_cor = 0.9999223

Cluster Type 2:
non-coding DOWN (e.g. noncodingA: 70.10, 30.02, 10.1)
coding DOWN     (e.g. codingC: 80.33, 15.02, 3.2)
pearson_cor = 0.982148

Cluster Type 3:
non-coding DOWN (e.g. noncodingZ: 80.33, 15.02, 3.2)
coding UP       (e.g. noncodingK: 10.00, 13.5, 40.10)
pearson_cor = -0.6981876

Cluster Type 4:
non-coding UP   (e.g. codingF: 1.00, 7.34, 50.10)
coding DOWN     (e.g. noncodingM: 70.10, 30.02, 10.1)
pearson_cor = -0.8274582
```

What I mean by UP and DOWN is the `expression trend through cell lineage`.
What's the right method to perform such kind of clustering?